# Python pyramid practice question generated different output

Tags: python

I was practicing pyramid patterns for a test in python. One question was about a pyramid pattern including 1s and 0s.

Output to generate:

```
1
10
101
1010
10101
```

Output that I got:

```
10
110
1110
11110
111110
```

My Efforts for this problem statement:

```
def pattern(n):
    for i in range(n):
        num = 1
        for j in range(i+1):
            print(num,end="")
        print(num-1)
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Why do you expect the `print` in your `for` loop to ever print a **0**?

Comment: @Steve I used `print` in for loop so that it prints 1 first time and 0 the next time. and again assigning 1 to `num`.

Comment: But as the answers show, you weren't changing `num` in your loop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change `num` each time you go through the `for j in range(i+1):` loop, otherwise you'll just keep printing the same number like in your output.  You could try changing `num` in each pass through the loop.  The modulus operator `%` will be useful for switching back and forth between 0 and 1:

```
def pattern(n):
    for i in range(n):
        num = 1
        for j in range(i+1):
            print(num,end="")
            num = (num+1)%2
```

Comment: Thankyou. This worked perfectly. But why doesn't the code work when I write `num = 0` ,  even when`(num+1)%2` is equal to 0 ?

Comment: If you start with `num=0` you should get a similar pattern just starting with 0 instead of 1, since `num` is printed before the line `num = (num+1)%2`

Answer (score 1):

because output format is `1010101`, you should change `num` in loop, and you can use XOR `^` to switch between `0` and `1`:

```
    def pattern(n):
        for i in range(n):
            num = 1
            for j in range(i+1):
                print(num, end="")
                num ^= 1
            print()
```

test:

```
pattern(5)
```

output:

```
1
10
101
1010
10101
```